# Angularjs bootstrap datepicker in inline form (is it possible>

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, angularjs-bootstrap

I have bootstrap inline form. When I integrated the Angularjs bootstrap datepicker, the datepicker text field is going in second line and breaks the shape of the bootstrap inline form. Any way I can avoid that?

```css
<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
        
    <div class="col-md-2,form-group" style=" width: 185px;">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
  
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Thank you